# Missing values in correlation calculation

Tags: r

Input:

```
 x   y
30  20
30  20
30  20
30  20
```

I try to calculate the correlation between two variables using cor() functions. In the input data there are no NA but I take the following result:

```
   a  b
a  1 NA
b NA  1
Warning message:
In cor(dataframe) :
    the standard deviation is zero
```

Why this happen? I tried to use the use of cor function but again the same results.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your input data, or a sample of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message 'the standard deviation is zero' suggests that (at least) one of the variables is constant and this makes it impossible to calculate its correlations with others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if the variables are constant than it is the appropriate/right output?

Comment: I would agree with R that NA is quite appropriate.